# Error states that prop is not specified

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make something fairly similar to the todos app in order to learn how react works with meteor.

My current code is as follows:

`BoardContainer.jsx`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Boards } from '../../api/boards/boards.js';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import BoardPage from '../pages/BoardPage.jsx';

export default BoardContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params;
  const board = Boards.findOne(id);

  return {
    board,
    boards: Boards.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, BoardPage);
```

`BoardPage.jsx`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import BoardList from '../components/BoardList.jsx';

export default class BoardPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { board, boards } = this.props;

    return (
      <main id="page">
        <BoardList boards={boards} />

        <div id="board">
          <h1>{board.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

BoardPage.propTypes = {
  board: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  boards: PropTypes.array,
};

BoardPage.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object,
};
```

The board page doesn't load and gives the following error: "Warning: Failed propType: Required prop 'board' was not specified in 'BoardPage'. Check the render method of 'MeteorDataContainer'," as well as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined."

Not sure why it is throwing this error, as I thought I correctly defined it in the container file.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me.... check the value of `board` in `BoardContainer.jsx`.

Comment: board is undefined... make sure BoardPage is getting the prop.